# Flutter where i can find the orange thing in this code please

Tags: flutter

i have this login page [image]

```
here is the code `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pharmaciemobile/src/homePage.dart';
import 'package:pharmaciemobile/src/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:pharmaciemobile/src/signup.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';


import 'Widget/bezierContainer.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String _email, _password;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey=GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget _backButton() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 10, bottom: 10),
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Color(0xff48fb51)/*Colors.black*/),
            ),
           /* Text('Back',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))*/
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }



  Widget _divider() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Divider(
                thickness: 1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text('or'),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Divider(
                thickness: 1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget _createAccountLabel() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpPage()));
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Don\'t have an account ?',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Text(
              'Register',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff48fb51),
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _title() {
    return RichText(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      text: TextSpan(
          text: 'Geolocalisation',
          style: GoogleFonts.portLligatSans(
            textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            fontSize: 25,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: 'des',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Pharmacies',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      height: height,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
              top: -height * .15,
              right: -MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
              child: BezierContainer()),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: height * .2),
                  _title(),
                  SizedBox(height: 30),
                  //_emailPasswordWidget(),
                  Form(
                    key : _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Email',
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                  validator : (input){
                                    if(input.isEmpty){
                                      return 'Please type an Email';
                                    }
                                  },
                                  onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      fillColor: Color(0xfff3f3f4),
                                      filled: true)
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                          child : Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Password',
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                  validator : (input){
                                    if(input.length<6){
                                      return 'Your Password is week';
                                    }
                                  },
                                  onSaved: (input) => _password = input,
                                  obscureText: true,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      fillColor: Color(0xfff3f3f4),
                                      filled: true)),
                              SizedBox(height: 20),

                            ],
                          ),

                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                          onPressed: signIn,
                          child:  Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                      offset: Offset(2, 4),
                                      blurRadius: 5,
                                      spreadRadius: 2)
                                ],
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    colors: [Color(0xff48fb51), Color(0xff10d2e4)])),
                            child: Text(
                              'se connecter',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ) ,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),




                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Text('Mot de passe oublié',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                  ),
                  _divider(),
                  //_facebookButton(),
                  //SizedBox(height: height * .055),
                  _createAccountLabel(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(top: 40, left: 0, child: _backButton()),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
Future<void> signIn() async {
    final formState = _formKey.currentState;
    if(formState.validate()){
      formState.save();
      try{
        AuthResult result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
        FirebaseUser user = result.user;
       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>HomePage()));
      }catch(e){
        print(e.message);
      }
    }

}

}
```

****i'    am   new   in   flutter   i     found     a   project   in    github ,    now i    want just    to     delete     the    orange   thing   somoene can help me please,i just want to delete the orange thing in the top somone can tell me were i can find it in the code please**

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the orange widget is this

```
Positioned(
top: -height * .15,
right: -MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
child: BezierContainer()),
```

in the future, if you want to inspect flutter widgets i recommend using Flutter inspector
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector